# Replace misspelled words from dictionary

Tags: java

I am trying to finish this algorithm that is supposed to replace a misspelled word in a txt file with a replacement word. As you can see the algorithm is described by the comments above and I have the first two parts done but am stuck on the `for each line number where it appears:`  part. I am having issues trying to figure out how to set up the loop. If anyone could help me towards the direction of finishing this method I would greatly appreciate it!

```
private void replace(String misspelled, String replacement){
    //TODO: Algorithm:
    //If wrongWords contains the misspelled word:
    //   get ALL the lineNumbers on where the misspelled word appears
    //   for each line number where it appears:
    //        in fileLines[line] replace misspelled with replacement
    //        (Hint: use one of the available methods in the String class to do the replacement)
    if(wrongWords.containsKey(misspelled))
       wrongWords.get(misspelled);

}
```

Other notable code that you may find useful includes:

```
private void correctionMode(){   
  for(String line: fileLine)
    for(String w: line.split("//s"))
       if(wrongWords.containsKey(w)){
           System.out.println(wrongWords.get(w));
           System.out.println("replace all? (y or n): ");
           String r = scan.nextLine();
           if(r.equals("y")){
               System.out.println("Enter replacement: ");
               String r2 = scan.nextLine();
               replace(w, r2);
           }
           wrongWords.remove(w);
       }                        
}
```

This methods asks the user for corrections and then goes to the replacement method, the one i am having issues with, if the user wants to make a change.

```
private Scanner scan; // a Scanner to read user's input
private HashSet<String> dictionary;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> wrongWords;
private ArrayList<String> fileLine;

\\constructor
public SpellChecker(){
  scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  dictionary = new HashSet<String>();
  wrongWords = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>(); //array is line numbers where misspelled word appears
  fileLine = new ArrayList<String>(); //each line is as separate element in the arraylist
}
```

The class variables and constructor may also be helpful.

Comment: Could you show us the sample how it is given that the word is wrongly spelled? Like 2-3 lines.

Comment: @vikiiii twinkle twinkle lottle star how I.
lottle lamb its a world of laughter a.
world of tears. for example "lottle" isn't in the dictionary so it is considered to be spelled incorrectly

Comment: `line.split("//s")` will not do what you want.  Slashes and backslashes are not the same thing.  You probably meant `"\\s"`.

Comment: @VGR Ah ha, you are correct. That one slipped by me. Still doesn't solve my replace method issue though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put for loop in both the methods for every line.

```
 //   for each line number where it appears:
```

and

```
for(String line: fileLine)
```

Put it in either one of it:

```
private void replace(String misspelled, String replacement){
         int i = 0;
         for(String line: fileLine) {
            if(line.contains(misspelled)) {
                line.replaceAll(misspelled, replacement);
                System.out.println("replaced word" + misspelled  + "in line number" + i );
                i++;
            }else i++;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason I have the correctionMode method done and now replace but when I run the program all it does is ask for the dictionary name and txt file name then just prints out the txt file. So the correctionMode method isn't even running...

Comment: oops just realized i didn't complete a method. ignore that comment and thanks for the help!